# How to turn off TwilightManager logging

Tags: android, location, location-services

I'm working on an Android app that does not need location services, and I don't want to add that permission.

While I'm testing on my physical device (Moto G5 Plus with Android 8.1.0), I see in Logcat the following repeated ad nauseam:

> TwilightManager: Could not get last known location. This is probably because the app does not have any location permissions. Falling back to hardcoded sunrise/sunset values.

I don't want it, I don't need it.  I can't figure out how to get rid of it.

`android.support.v7.app.TwilightManager.isNight()` is apparently getting called by something, but I'm not sure how to tell it not to keep calling it.

I tried several *get system service* kinds of things, but never found the secret handshake.  Besides, TwilightManager is private.

```
getBlahBlahService(android.support.v7.app.TwilightManager.class);  
//'android.support.v7.app.TwilightManager' is not public in 'android.support.v7.app'. Cannot be accessed from outside package
```

Comment: Call `getDelegate()` on your `AppCompatActivity`, then play around with methods like `setDefaultNightMode()`. If you use something other than `MODE_NIGHT_AUTO`, I think you might avoid those logs.

Answer (score 1):

One way to stop the logging is to tell TwilightManager not to use night mode:

`AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)`

This can be run from your first activity.

Alternatively, you could see why TwilightManager thinks it needs to do anything for you in the first place.  Check your `styles.xml`.  Do you have any *daynight* themes?

`<style name="CommonTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar">`

You might consider alternatives.